# Multiple Custom Tags in Javadoc Displayed Separately?

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

When building our documentation, we've decided to use some custom tags to add details at a class level, leveraging Ant tasks for the build. Here's a sample of the ant task target:

```
<target name="doc">
    <javadoc 
        access="public" 
        additionalparam=" -tag SequenceStep:a:&quot;Sequence Step:&quot;"
        author="true" 
        destdir="ant/doc" 
        doctitle="Test"
        nodeprecated="false" 
        nodeprecatedlist="false" 
        noindex="true" 
        nonavbar="true" 
        notree="true" 
        source="1.6" 
        sourcepath="${src.dir};${test.dir}" 
        splitindex="false" 
        use="false" 
        version="true"
        private="on"
        failonerror="false">
            <classpath path="${full.test.classpath}" />
    </javadoc>
```

Internal to the class I've been testing, here's a sample Javadoc:

```
/**
 * @SequenceStep {@link package.DummyClass#methodOne()} Method one specifics
 * 
 * @SequenceStep {@link package.DummyClass#methodTwo()} Method two specifics
 */
```

My generated Javadoc gives me a section that looks like this:

> **Sequence Step:**
>
> methodOne() Method one specifics, methodTwo() Method two specifics

My expectation was to get something more equivalent to how @param works, listing one per use of the tag.

Can anyone provide suggestions on how to instead get one of the following outputs, if possible?

> **Sequence Step:**
>
> methodOne() Method one specifics
>
> methodTwo() Method two specifics

or

> **Sequence Step:**
>
> methodOne() Method one specifics
>
> **Sequence Step:**
>
> methodTwo() Method two specifics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @SequenceStep 
 * <p>{@link package.DummyClass#methodOne()} Method one specifics</p>
 * <p>{@link package.DummyClass#methodTwo()} Method two specifics</p>
 */
```

Comment: I agree that as a workaround, that gets me there, but I was hoping not to have to get all our developers to have to know to embed HTML in their code.

Comment: In that case, I noticed these other javadoc options that might help: -taglet and -tagletpath. That said, knowledge of some simple HTML tags is both common and useful. I personally would consider this more of a training problem.

Comment: Knowledge of html isn't an issue, I was simply looking for an alternative. I did see the -taglet option, however I did not see any specifics that indicate they can be done multiple times. Can you point me toward specifics that indicate as much?

Comment: I haven't implemented a taglet. Looking at the example code at the URL below, it looks like there's a method that accepts an array of Tag instances. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/ToDoTaglet.java

Comment: Thanks - i suspect that's going to do the trick. I definitely didn't get that on the first few read-throughs of that sample, even though I looked at that very one.

I'll give it a shot tomorrow and post my results.